# Typescript Import vs JavaScript import

Tags: javascript, typescript

/module/c.js, trying to export name and age.

```
export const name = 'string1';
export const age = 43;
```

b.ts , I'm trying to import name and age in this .ts file

```
import { name, age } from "./module/c";
console.log(name, age);
```

Compile will get error like this: "TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './module/c'."

I search and found a workaround:  using // @ts-ignore, this can ignore grammar validation..

```
// @ts-ignore
import { name, age } from "./module/c";
console.log(name, age);
```

Question: This is a abnormal way for such kind of issue, is there any other ways to fix the issue?
Btw, will be great if there's an example.. thx

Comment: You say *"a.js, trying to export name and age."*, then *"import { name, age } from "./module/c";"*. Why do you think TS can find some symbols in the `module/c` module when you declare them in the `a` module?

Comment: typo, sorry, it's "c.js", will update it..

Comment: c.js is under./module/ folder, that's the reason why I use "import { name, age } from "./module/c"

Comment: How to make it work without this line "// @ts-ignore"?

Comment: Well, you try to import from a `.js` file, which doesn't have any type declarations for the exported bindings. Either make it `c.ts`, or provide a separate [declaration file](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html)

Comment: @Bergi Typo..  actually, It is "c.js" under "/module" folder, types declared in it. problem is how to make it work without the code "// @ts-ignore"?

Comment: @Codex If you did declare types inside it, please update the code in your question. Can you try renaming the file to `.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `c.js` is a JavaScript file, you should set `"allowJs": true` in your tsconfig.json file to allow importing from a `.js` file.

An example of a `tsconfig.json` file would be:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

*src/b.ts*

```
import { name, age } from "./module/c";
console.log(name, age);
```

*src/module/c.js*

```
export const name = 'string1';
export const age = 43;
```

Output of executing `node dist/b`:

```
string1 43
```